# Vibration- Samsung Galaxy Ace

Tags: samsung-galaxy-ace, haptic-feedback

Can anyone guide me or advise on how to disable the in-built vibration for holding down on the screen whilst copy/paste to the clipboard?

Have searched in Settings and cannot find it.

Answer (score 1):

I've checked the settings in my devices as I knew I've seen it somewhere.

- On my Tabbies with 4.1.1: nothing found.
- My Wildfire with 4.0.4 running CyanogenMod 9.1 has it in the Audio/Tone menu as *Vibrate on touch*
- my Milestone 2 (CM7.2/Gingerbread) has it at the same place as *haptic feedback*
- LG Optimus 4X (aka LG-P880) running stock 4.0.3: Again same place, *Vibrate on touch*

So the location of this setting seems to be quite clear -- but some manufacturers seem to have the setting removed/hidden. If your device belongs to that group, take a look at [Spare Parts Plus! (no ads)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.droidgram.spareparts), which offers this setting at the end of its main screen as *haptic feedback* (the app is free and has no ads).

Answer (score 0):

On my Galaxy S3, the Haptic Feedback (Vibrate when soft keys are pressed and on certain UI interactions) is part of the Sound Settings. I never have them on, but to test for this question, turned it on, and performed a copy/paste operation to encounter what you felt. It was successful, so undo it by going to sound, and disabling Haptic Feedback.

Answer (score -1):

If you dwn load the nq smart booster app when using the app to optimize the battery ,the haptic appears and u can enable or disable it accordingly, its does not appear in d settings.

Comment: Would you mind to use proper english and could you include a link to that app?